# Looking to reference one class in another

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to create a sort of basketball simulation. This is what I have so far:

```
import random
from scipy.stats import norm

class teams:
    def __init__(self, pytho, pythd, coach, coachdev):
        self.pytho = pytho
        self.pythd = pythd
        self.coach = coach
        self.coachdev = coachdev

    def adjpytho(self):
        print((norm.ppf(random.random()) * self.coachdev + self.coach) + self.pytho)

    def adjpythd(self):
        print((norm.ppf(random.random()) * self.coachdev + self.coach) + self.pythd)

class game:
    def __init__(self, team1, team2):
        self.team1 = team1
        self.team2 = team2

    def points(self, team1, team2):
        print(teams.adjpytho(team1) - teams.adjpythd(team2))



Florida = teams(.90, .84, .06, .05)
Alabama = teams(.88, .83, .04, .06)
Oklahoma = teams(.81, .78, .06, .1)
Virginia = teams(.77, .99, .04, .06)


print(game.points(self, Florida, Virginia))
```

As you can see, I've set up the initial "teams" class and it works fine. In it, I have the four main parameters for each team, and then two of them I adjust (The "adjpytho" and "adjpythd").

However, I want to now get the actual simulation of the game, and I'm struggling. I tried to set up a "game" class that brings in two parameters (the two teams playing in the game). But when I get to the "points" part of the class, I run into issues.

In "points", I want to pull the teams.adjpytho(Florida), for example, and then teams.adjpythd(Virginia). For ease, I just subtracted to the two and the end result should be what prints out on the console.

I tried to do

```
print(game.points(self, Florida, Virginia))
```

but that wasn't working. Any hints?

Comment: We don't know what "wasn't working" means.

Answer (score 2):

In `teams.adjpytho(team1)`, `teams` is a class name and `team1` is a variable name. The correct way to invoke a method on an object is this:

```
team1.adjpytho()
```

So you do not need to mention the class name at all. Python will figure out that `team1` is an instance of the class `teams` (you should really rename this to `team`, by the way - class names should be singular), and `teams1` will automatically be passed as the `self` parameter.

As for `game`, you need to create an instance of it first, and then call `points()` on that. Furthermore, `points()` doesn't need the `team1` and `team2` parameters, as you've already provided the teams as constructor parameters and assigned them to variables - they will be available as `self.team1` and `self.team2`, so inside `points()`, you can do e.g. `self.team1.adjpytho()`. Then, you call it like this:

```
g = game(Florida, Virginia)
g.points()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  print(teams.adjpytho(team1) - teams.adjpythd(team2))
```

Change this to:

```
  str(teams.adjpytho(team1) - teams.adjpythd(team2))
```

Because print is a python command that puts something in the screen then returns 0. str() takes something and makes it into a string, which then can be printable.

Comment: Are you sure of your answer?

Comment: You are right about what `str()` does, but `print()` can print anything.

Comment: As sure as they get, as clear as daylight, with a golden star on top.